# Loop locally through files on remote server

Tags: bash, ssh

I need to convert on my local machine some videos residing on a remote server.

My approach is:

1. Use ssh to get a list of file
2. Download one by one in the loop and process it

The problem is that those files have whitespaces.

I've tried this approach

```
filels=`ssh $USER@$SERVER ls "$FOLDER*.avi"`
IFS='\n'
for f in $filels; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

But still it does not work. A single file name is split in 3 parts like this:

```
My super very
long filename
is splitted
```

What is the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Try to quote names with **ls** and use bash array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

filels="( $(ssh $USER@$SERVER ls -Q "$FOLDER*.avi") )"
IFS='\n' for f in $filels; do
echo "$f" done
```

**ls** option

```
-Q, --quote-name
          enclose entry names in double
          quotes
```

Or if you have **rsync**:

```
~$ rsync -var --progress $USER@$SERVER:/PATH_TO_FOLDER/*avi ./
# do anything with files
```

Comment: I'd suggest using Hellseher's rsync recommendation. This will save you much grief + hair pulling.

Answer (score 0):

You also could use a here string in combination with a `while` loop.

```
filels=`ssh $USER@$SERVER ls "$FOLDER*.avi"`

while read f 
do 
    echo "${f}"
done <<< "$filels"
```